# How to overwrite records with similar existing values

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

I have been searching for a way to do the following task through a stored procedure:

1)Take the date range to fetch data.

2)if data for a date in date range exists, over write the values of corresponding regardless of any changes.

3)if not, then insert new.

So basically, I want it to do it based on the date and not the primary key. primary key or unique key is not relevant hence i can not use `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY` OR `REPLACE INTO`.

Can anyone please suggest me a a way to do it through a single query?Something like this:
`INSERT INTO t1 values(....) ON DUPLICATE 'column_name' UPDATE column_names = 'new_column_values'`

or there is no way but to do the traversing for every record that qualifies for the date range?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "if data for the data range exists"?  What about partially overlapping ranges?  What do you do when one range totally encompasses another?

Comment: its not data for data ranges..its 'if data for a DATE in DATE range exists'..there would only be given one date range and records will be inserted after fetching data that has been stored on a 'date' that lies within that 'date' range.hence, i want to over write if a record for a 'date' already exists with the most update fetch.